# JList won't show up on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlist

Everything works except for the fact that the list doesn't show up on the JFrame. I don't understand why I can't add things without declaring a new layout.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

public class Gui3 extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mousepanel;
    private JLabel statusbar;
    private JList list;
    private static String[] colornames = {"black","blue","red","white"};
    private static Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE,Color.RED,Color.WHITE};

    public Gui3(){
        super("The title");

        list = new JList(colornames);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(4);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setFixedCellHeight(15);
        list.setFixedCellWidth(100);
        add(new JScrollPane(list));
        list.addListSelectionListener(
                new ListSelectionListener(){
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event){
```

The user should be able to select the background color from the list and then the program should change the background to that color. But is isn't...

```
mousepanel.setBackground(colors[list.getSelectedIndex()]);

                    }
                }
            );

        mousepanel = new JPanel();
        mousepanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(mousepanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        statusbar = new JLabel("Default");
        add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 


        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        mousepanel.addMouseListener(handler);
        mousepanel.addMouseMotionListener(handler);

    }   
    private class HandlerClass implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
        {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            statusbar.setText(String.format("Clicked at %d, %d", event.getX(),event.getY()));
            DrawShapes shapes = new DrawShapes();
            shapes.setPosition(event.getX(), event.getY());
            add(shapes);

        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
            statusbar.setText("You pressed down the mouse");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
            statusbar.setText("You released the button");
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){
            statusbar.setText("You entered the area");
            mousepanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){
            statusbar.setText("The mouse has left the window");
            mousepanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        //These are mouse motion events
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){
            statusbar.setText("You are dragging the mouse");
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event){
            statusbar.setText("You are moving the mouse");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You `JList` is there, it's just empty. How are you running it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you use `BorderLayout` but don't set position for `ScrollPane`. So, `mousePanel` will lie on `ScrollPane`.

Try this

```
add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Comment: @BobbyC.Robillard, if this helped solve the problem the don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved. This applies to your previous questions as well.